# How to find the print data of python in linux?

Tags: python, linux

I have a web server to provide web service on port 8080, which was like:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

and there are some code like `print(KEY)` in main.py.
I want to know if it is possible to get the print data via /proc/self/xx. I have search the [proc doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) but cant find anything useful.Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Flask has a `logging` module.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
```